# How can I cite a report written by a Congressman in MLA Style?

Tags: citations

The report is called The Path Forward: Rethinking Federal Policy on Marijuana. I have no idea how to cite this online source. It seems confusing since it isn't a bill but rather just something he wrote to inform. Website: https://blumenauer.house.gov/sites/blumenauer.house.gov/files/BlumenauerReport_ThePathForward.pdf

Comment: This question would fit better in the Writing StackExchange:
https://writing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Whether here or on Writing.SE, we'd need to know what citation style you're using.  It'll probably be treated like an unpublished article.

Comment: I edited my question. It was MLA.

Answer (score 2):

I searched google scholar to find your article [The path forward: rethinking federal marijuana policy](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=the%20path%20forward%20rethinking%20federal%20marijuana%20policy&btnG=) and from there you can cite it using several different formats including MLA by clicking the double quotation symbol as shown in the figures below:

[image]

---

[image]

Also in the second figure you can click the BibTeX link.

Comment: In my experience, Google Scholar's suggested citation style often fails for non-standard formats such as this. Also, I have found that Google Scholar's suggested citation often contains errors for scientific articles.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different ways I might cite it. I have included the examples from the page I link to.

First, you could cite it as a [webpage](https://columbiacollege-ca.libguides.com/mla/websites):

> Poncelet, Barbara. "Mom Am I Fat?: Helping Your Teen Have a Positive Body Image." Verywell.com, About Inc., 20 Apr. 2016, www.verywell.com/mom-am-i-fat-3200843. Accessed 7 July 2016.

Second, you could cite it as a [Government Document](https://columbiacollege-ca.libguides.com/mla/govdocs)

> Highlights from the Competition Bureau’s Workshop on Emerging Competition Issues. Competition Bureau of Canada, 4 Mar. 2016, www.competitionbureau.gc.ca/eic/site/cb-bc.nsf/vwapj/cb-Workshop-Summary-Report-e.pdf/$FILE/cb-Workshop-Summary-Report-e.pdf. Accessed 6 July 2016.

I would **not** use Google Scholar's suggested citation. In my own experience, the suggestions are often poorly formatted for "grey" literature and contain errors for scientific article citation details.